# How to create sessions in a strong way and store them in cookies in node js?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

In my login module once I log in I pass my request to a header to store a session here is the code

```
        var series = rand.generate(16);
        var token = rand.generate(16);
        var loginToken = new LoginTokens({
            userId: req.user._id,
            series: series,
            token: token
        });

        loginToken.save(function(err, l) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(l);
                res.cookie('loginToken', JSON.stringify({
                    series: series,
                    token: passwordHash.generate(token)
                }));

                res.status(200);
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    'success': req.params.res
                }));
            }
        });
```

Though this code was pre-written and I don't understand it much(I don't get the point of randomly generating 16 digit number and saving it if somebody does please explain)

I have been tasked with implementing log out and As I don't understand the rationale behind above code I want to implement my own session module such that even if the same user logs in from a different device, both sessions will be maintained and logging out from one device will not log out someone from all device. 
So now the point comes that the session id will not be based on user id. Also there is a module called express-session which I don't know if I should use or not, personally I feel that after reading it up on GitHub that what it will do is create a session id for me, which again I will have to save in my database, so why to import a module, instead I will base64 encode a random number like above and use it.
So what I want to ask is the real question

How do you implement sessions in node js?

My understanding of life cycle

1. A user signs up you see if he/she exists in the database and if he does you raise an error message and if he/she doesn't you create a username for him, probably by email id.
2. You then via code log him in. In that process, you first check if he is there in the database. If he is you go ahead take the `_id` field and try and create a session object. **Ques** what does your session table should look like? What all parameters should be present in sessions table? Then how do save them into res.cookies? Then what do you do with all those cookies, like on client side?
3. While implementing logout. My thinking is using passport.logout will remove the user object from request header but, I will have to first remove the entry from sessions table somehow empty the cookies and then do req.logout?

Can somebody please answer the above doubts? 
I asked a very specific question but realised after the comment that what I need is logical clarity and I did not find one on youtube videos nor on SO posts, so if someone can share their views mostly in code, with some explanation it would be great.

Comment: So a few things that might help you get answers:

What are you actually using on the server site, plain vanilla http? it looks like you've got connect thrown in there, and passport, what's actually intercepting the web request at the server? 

What's being sent over the wire? have you tried actually looking at the network requests to see if your cookie is being sent back and forth? 

seems like passport is picking up your user so why aren't you using passport methods? http://passportjs.org/docs/logout

Comment: I am using passport using passport.logout() will delete the user property. I am asking how do I manage sessions? Storing what data in my sessions table to have secure sessions and what data to save into res.cookies and then how to delete them all to have a clean interface such that even if the same user logs in from two different devices it will maintain two different sessions and log out from whichever account he logs out. A code example would be great?

Comment: I think you're confused, passport _is_ your session management it has all the functions you need. login, authorise and logout. It'll handle all the cookies for you. See Disable Sessions under authenticate here to see how you turn it off: http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate. I'm not sure what more you're trying to add on top.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies get deleted by sending a new cookie with the same name (some invalid data would be good) and an expiry in the past.

passport.logout() removes the session cookie that passport uses to maintain the current user, the next request will no longer have the cookie and will appear as an invalid request.

I'm not sure why there's a loginToken as well as passport authentication, apart from allowing you to invalidate sessions server side (by deleting the appropriate token from the database) Check if your passport strategy configuration has any checks against LoginToken during it's deserialize user step (this is where passport takes the session cookie and turns it into a user against the request)

Comment: my question is suppose 10 users login. Will passport save the session data for all of them? if yes, how does this save this information and where?

Comment: each user login creates a cookie which is a signed encrypted cookie version of their login data (the user they're currently logged in as) the cookie is the source of data for passport so it depends what you put into serialize and deserialize user (see under configure => sessions here http://passportjs.org/docs/overview) that's where you turn the data from the cookie into a user and from the user into a cookie. Often all you need to do is send the id over the wire in the cookie.

Then the cookie lifetime decides how long the user is valid for, or until you log the user out

Comment: I read the passportjs docs. I must say it's much clear now. Will comment more after working. There is no good screencast that I could find. Do you happen to know any?